# Conditional Expectation for a Gaussian Process

Tags: conditional-probability, stochastic-processes, gaussian-process, conditional-expectation

For a stochastics process $\{X_t\}_{t=0}$ with a filtration $\left\{\mathcal{F}_t\right\}_{t \geq 0}$ where $\cdots \mathcal{F}_{t-1} \subseteq \mathcal{F}_{t} \subseteq \cdots \subseteq \mathcal{F}_{\infty}$ and $\mathcal{F}_t = \sigma\left(X_s, s \leq t\right)$ (e.g. $\mathcal{F}_t$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra with respect to which all the variables ($X_s$, $s \leq t$) are measurable), let we consider a Gaussian process
\begin{equation}
Y_{t+1}=f(X_t, t+1)+\epsilon_{t+1}, \quad f(X_t,t+1) \sim \mathcal{G} \mathcal{P}\left(m_{t+1}(X_t), k_{t+1}\left(X_t, X^{\prime}_{t}\right)\right)
\end{equation}

e.g. consider a set of data $(Y_{t+1}, X_t)$ so that we would like to estimate mean function $f(X_t, t+1)$, in which $f(X_t, t+1)$ is the prediction at $t+1$ with input $X_t$.

I was wondering if the $f(X_t, t+1)$ is still a random under the filtration $\mathcal{F}_{t}$? e.g., can we have the conditional expectation $E(f(X_t, t+1) | \mathcal{F}_{t}) = m_{t+1}(X_t)$?

My guess is no as there is no uncertainty after conditioning the realization of $X_t$ at time $t$?

What makes me confusing is that, if I treat $f(X_t,t+1)$ as the prediction of the **unknown** mean function of $Y_t$,  $$Y_{t+1} = g(X_{t}, t+1) + \epsilon_{t+1}$$
with $\hat{g}(X_{t}, t+1 | \mathcal{F}_{t} ) = f(X_t, t+1)$. In this case, can we have $E(f(X_t,t+1) | \mathcal{F}_{t}) = m_{t+1}(X_t)$?

Comment: By your definition of $\mathcal{F}_t$, $f(X_t)$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable (we don't even need to know if $f(X_t)$ is a Gaussian process), hence $E[f(X_t)|\mathcal{F}_t] = f(X_t)$ by conditional expectation property.

Comment: @Zhanxiong In this case, f(X_t) is deterministic function? But in GP setting, f() is unknown and its estimate is random variable?

Comment: I refine my question and hope it is clear enough. Thanks a lot